# bcp outfile not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to run the script below, but it returns null. When I run the DOS command, it generates the file normally.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)
SET @str = 'bcp "Select * FROM WDG.dbo.Facilidade" queryout "w:\xyzTable.txt" -S "WDG-NOTE24\MSSQLWDG" -T -c -t ; '
EXEC xp_cmdshell @str
GO
```

I need to return a separate txt file for ';' with query data

Tanks

Comment: Mine is returning fine. Are you sure you wrote your DBName correct? And what does the error says?

Comment: Yes, because I ran in DOS to return the data, so I did not put the connection data in sql bcp

Comment: but what does your error says?

Comment: Do not create the file

Comment: Can you paste the rows it prints out? Maybe its because your service agent doesnt have access to your path

Comment: I tried that way too. "SET @str = 'bcp "Select * FROM WDG.dbo.Facilidade" queryout "w:\xyzTable.txt" -S "WDG-NOTE24\MSSQLWDG" -T -c -t ; -Usa -p123@qwe'"

Comment: Please paste the output of when you execute your statement

Comment: Result=Null
Mensage= 1 line affected

Comment: Do you have a BCP.exe in 90/tools/binn  folder under program files\Microsoft sQL ?

Comment: Check this folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server and for all version check if you have more BCP than one. You should only have one. I Just searched the folders for BCP. There should only be one in 120 or 130 or 140 depending on what version of sql-server you use.

Comment: I was missing a dll, I installed now it shows the error

SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL

Comment: That error comes when you dont have access to your folderpath.

Answer (score 0):

Given your error in your comments i will follow this link and as i described earlier its an access problem to your folder.

Remember it should be given to your Sql service account user and not your self

[BCP unable to open BCP host access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128855/unable-to-open-bcp-host-data-file-using-xp-cmdshell-from-ssms-but-command-line)

Comment: did not work
I gave the folder full permission for all SQL users //
I tried to run without the file in the directory //
I created a new empty file //
I changed the directory //

Run Management Studio as ADM

Comment: I had released permission from all users to the folder, and the SA already had access to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, I found the command below that tests if it has access to the directory.

For some reason did not accept the old path, so I created another one on another disk and it worked.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR C:\sql'
```

Very thank's for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem, at the end of my import file, it comes with the text '--END--', and when the bulk insert is going to render, it displays an unexpected end message.

I can put some parameter so that when it finds the text it finishes the import.

```
        declare @sql varchar(max)
        set @sql = 'BULK INSERT Temp_Facilite FROM ''' + @@FullPath + '''WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,CODEPAGE = ''RAW'',FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'',MAXERRORS = 3,  KEEPNULLS );'
        exec (@sql)
```